# viewDidLoad in iOS 6 called once?

Tags: ios, uikit, ios6, viewdidload

**Head's up:** This question is related to the recent [deprecation of `viewDidUnload`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidUnload). I have seen ["great" and logical answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12709694/456434) around this topic, but apparently [they were proven wrong](http://thejoeconwayblog.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/view-controller-lifecycle-in-ios-6/). Proceed with caution, this topic is very confusing as you see.

[From Apple's Docs:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW15)

> However, the system automatically releases these expensive resources 
>   when the view is not attached to a window. The remaining memory
>   used by most views is small enough that it is not worth it for the
>   system to automatically purge and recreate the view hierarchy.

So... Can I safely assume in iOS 6 that, as long as I don't explicitly set the viewController's view to nil (unload it manually), `viewDidLoad` will only be called only once for any allocated viewController instance throughout the lifetime of the application?

Comment: I found that in iOS 6, viewDidLoad would be called twice when I set the ViewController's orientation to landscape.

Comment: @DJean I believe your answer is more accurate than the current accepted answer.

Comment: @DJean how do you "set" a `UIViewController`s orientation to landscape? Programmatically? When I do it by rotating the device, either manually or [programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20987296/242933), `viewDidLoad` isn't called again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of iOS 6, your `UIViewController` subclass will only receive `viewDidLoad` once, unless you write code to set its `view` back to `nil`.

However, I wouldn't rely on that behavior in a complex system-provided view controller like `UIImagePickerController`.  Perhaps it sets its own `view` back to nil.