# Navigating to a main ViewController that is already loaded without loading it again

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a main view controller that loads some data from API, from there I move to another screen which shows details for a particular deal. I want to go back to the main controller, but when I use `prepareForSegue`, it goes back to the main controller, but it loads the data again making an API call. I want to retain the state of the main controller.

Please help me as how to retain the state of a view controller and how to segue from the second controller to main controller without loading it again.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self FetchDeals];
    [self Getdeals];
}
```

The fetch deal method makes an API call and getdeals populates it into a tableview.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Dealdetail"])
    {
        //NSLog(@"New controller");
        DealDetailController *detail = (DealDetailController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        
        detail.detailimage = imagepath;
    }
}
```

DealDetailController is the second view controller from where I come back to the main control.

*Code in DealDetailController:*

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    MainappViewController *maincontrol = (MainappViewController *)[segue destinationViewController]; 
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code from your main ViewController?

Comment: Please find my edited code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want to use here is an **'Unwind Segue'**.

[This](http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2013/2/5/unwind-segues) blog post describes (with videos) how to do this.

Also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12416050/xcode-4-5-storyboard-exit) question where the answer points you toward the WWDC 2012 video which covers Unwind segues.

Comment: Sounds good. Is this limited to ios6? Not sure if that's of interest to the OP but just wanted to clarify. Also, I'm interested in the context of this [SO question - viewdidload in ios 6 called once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152304/viewdidload-in-ios-6-called-once). This may be useful to the OP.

Comment: Yes, good point. I think they are available only from iOS6. Having said that it's the same for Segues in general which are already in use  by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

use popViewController. it retains the state.
already you have loaded mainViewController that means it is on the stack.if you want again this viewController then simply use popViewController

Comment: -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{   
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
} It still Loads in main controller

Comment: @ankit_rck - you need to read up on Unwind Segues as per my answer.